# Cursror into string error cursor.getcolumnIndex Key_titles and therefore cant fill my arraylist

Tags: android, string, cursor

```
Cursor curz=mDbHelper.fetchAllRemindersG();
    startManagingCursor(curz);



    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String name =curz.getString(curz.getColumnIndex(DatabaseIN.KEY_TITLE));
    for(curz.moveToFirst(); curz.moveToNext(); curz.isAfterLast()) 
    {        mArrayList.add(name); }

    name_Val = (String[]) mArrayList.toArray(new String[mArrayList.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name_Val);
    txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am filling a autocompletetextview and i get an error at String name =curz.getString(curz.getColumnIndex(DatabaseIN.KEY_TITLE));
 it just can't get the correct column index it forcecloses  ive tried to wirte mdbHelper.KEY_TITLE or just KEY_TITLE but it was the same error

Comment: you have to provide the name of the column to `.getColumnIndex()`. That column has to exist in the database table you query and you need to include it in your query. (the projection argument of `query`)

Comment: public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
 public static final String KEY_DATAS = "datas";
 public static final String KEY_BODY = "body"; 
public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 HERE IS WHAT I HAVE IN MY DATABASE CLASS and i am trying to use the KEY_TITLE

Comment: String name =curz.getString(curz.getColumnIndexOrThrow(getString(0)));
i tried this and still error( if this is what u mean by getString(0)

Comment: `String name =curz.getString(0)`

Comment: it still forcecloses , maybe i have an error Cursor curz=mDbHelper.fetchAllRemindersG();     startManagingCursor(curz);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Cursor curz=mDbHelper.fetchAllRemindersG();
    startManagingCursor(curz);

   // setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    curz.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (curz.getCount() > 0)
    {
        do
        {

            String name = curz.getString(curz.getColumnIndex(DatabaseIN.KEY_TITLE));
            if(name!=null)
            {
                mArrayList.add(name);
            }
        }while (curz.moveToNext());

    }
```

Comment: -1 You should use do...While loop instead of while, because after using moveToFirst() in the while loop it uses moveToNext(). That means it will move to the 2nd row and start fetching from 2nd row.

Answer (score 1):

```
curz.moveToFirst()
String name =curz.getString(curz.getColumnIndex(DatabaseIN.KEY_TITLE));
do {        
    mArrayList.add(name); 
}while(curz.moveToNext());
```

First you need to move to first row, then you can get something from it. Because when cursor is created, the pointer points to the -1 index or you can say it points to beforeFirst.

Comment: well now it does'n force close but the autocompletetextview is not filling

Comment: as i can see in the debugger mArrayList.add(name) is not executing, from for line jumps after the for ciclus